# Fetching reddit posts in which the text is < 1024 characters

Tags: javascript, discord.js

`I am trying to fetch reddit posts onto my discord bot, but only want posts in which the text of the post is < 1024 characters as that is the limit of .addField in a RichEmbed. How would I go about doing that?

Currently I have:

```js
     const allowed = message.channel.nsfw ? body.data.children : 
     body.data.children.filter(post => !post.data.over_18);

     const postlength = body.data.children.filter(post => 
     !post.data.selftext.length > 1024);
        if (!postlength && !allowed.length) 
        return message.channel.send('It seems we are out of fresh memes!, Try again later.');

        const randomnumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * allowed.length)
        const embed = new Discord.RichEmbed()
        .setColor(0x00A2E8)
        .setTitle(allowed[randomnumber].data.title)
        .setDescription("Posted by: " + allowed[randomnumber].data.author)
        .addField("Post: ", allowed[randomnumber].data.selftext + allowed[randomnumber].data.selftext.length)
        .setImage(allowed[randomnumber].data.url)
        .addField("Other info:", "Up votes: " + allowed[randomnumber].data.ups + " / Comments: " + allowed[randomnumber].data.num_comments)
        .setFooter("Memes provided by r/dankmemes")
        message.channel.send(embed)
```

My variable `postlength`is where I try to filter out the reddit posts, however it seems to have no effect.

Answer (score 1):

### Solution

You're doing

```
filter(post => !post.data.selftext.length > 1024);
```

which will check if `false` is bigger than `1024`. I'm assuming you want to filer out and get all posts that have length smaller than 1024?

Change your code to...

```
filter(post => post.data.selftext.length < 1024);
```

---

### Explaination

When you add an exclamation mark `!` before a property, you will invert its truthiness. Something will be *Truthy* if it's not

- An empty string
- 0
- null
- undefined
- "false"
- false

In your case, you'll be inverting a string that does not suit the above, so it will be translated to false unless the length is actually 0:

```
!post.data.selftext.length
```